# Cauchy product and geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series, cauchy-product

I was given this series:

Let $q \in \mathbb{C}, \mid q\mid <1. $

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2 +3n +2)q^n $$

Now I have to show that

$$\frac{1}{(1-q)^3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^2 +3n +2)q^n$$

and proof whether or not this series converges absolutely.

For the convergence I guess I have to use one of the many convergence criteria and for the equality I have no clue how to even start.

Comment: The same of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355041/use-cauchy-product-to-find-a-power-series-represenitation-of-1-over-1-x3

Comment: But I think that the simplest route from a series representing $1/(1-q)$ to one representing $1/(1-q)^3$ is to differentiate it termwise twice. Of course, it is possible that in the current phase of your course Cauchy products have been covered but termwise differentiation of power series has not (yet!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$\frac1{1-q}=1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots,$$you have, by the Cauchy product,$$\begin{align}\frac1{(1-q)^2}&=\frac1{1-q}\times\frac1{1-q}\\&=\left(1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots\right)\times\left(1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots\right)\\&=1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+\cdots\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)q^n.\end{align}$$Now, in order to prove what you want to prove, apply the same idea to the equality$$\frac1{(1-q)^3}=\frac1{1-q}\times\frac1{(1-q)^2}$$and use the fact that$$(n+1)+n+(n-1)+\cdots+1=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2=\frac{n^2+3n+2}2.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "by the Cauchy Product"

Comment: I mean that the Cauchy product of the series $1+q+q^2+q^3+q^3+\cdots$ by itself is the series $1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+\cdots$

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know that could you give further explaination?

Comment: Simply apply the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series) of the Cauchy product.

Comment: If I understood you right by definition I get that the Cauchy product of the series $1+q +q^2+q^3+...$ with it self is: $\sum_{n=0}^kq^nq^{k-n}$ but this is not the desired result i.e. $1+2q+3q^2+4q^3 +...$

Comment: You did not understand the definition. The Cauchy product of $a_0+a_1q+a_2q^2+\cdots$ by $b_0+b_1q+b_2q^2+\cdots$ is $c_0+c_1q+c_2q^2$, where $c_k=a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\cdots+a_kb_0$. In your case, every $a_j$ and every $b_j$ is equal to $1$ and therefore$$c_k=\overbrace{1\times1+1\times1+\cdots+1\times1}^{k\text{ times}}=k+1.$$